# How to disable TileService for Android 34+ but keep for previous versions?

Tags: android, android-service, android-manifest

So starting from Android 34 TileService doesn't allow to start a foreground service and use *location* | *camera* | *mic* anymore (though no official info about it, at least we still can use widgets and shortcuts), so it's useless right now and I want to remove it for Android 34+.

In `AndroidManifest.xml` I have the following:

```
<service
    android:name="com.example.service.StartStopRecTileService"
    android:exported="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_test"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

How can I exclude it for Android 34+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your `service` element:

```xml
android:enabled="@bool/api_lt_34"
```

Define this in `values/bools.xml`:

```xml
    <bool name="api_lt_34">true</bool>
```

Override it in `values-v34/bools.xml`:

```xml
    <bool name="api_lt_34">false</bool>
```

Comment: @JeswinJoji the question here is not about launching an activity but starting a foreground service from TileService which will use camera or mic